# How to use Ava with Angular/CLI build typescript project

Tags: angular, testing, npm, ava

As a part of a project I am building I currently have an angular/cli typescript project I have created. We are currently using the karma testing framework, but are extremely interested in switching to AVA if possible.

I've currently done a `npm install --save-dev ava`
And I've looked at the typescript setup in the ava documentation 
https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/typescript.md

I've also followed the setup on the main page itself and added an "ava" section to my package.json

```
"ava": {
  "files": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "source": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "match": [],
  "concurrency": 5,
  "failFast": true,
  "failWithoutAssertions": false,
  "tap": true,
  "powerAssert": false,
  "require": [
    "babel-register"
  ],
  "babel": "inherit"
}
```

I've hoped that somehow by default this would pick up our currently written `spec.ts` files that have been tailored and written for karma, but it would seem that this isn't so as I'm only given

```
# Couldn't find any files to test
not ok 1 - Couldn't find any files to test

1..0
# tests 0
# pass 0
# fail 1
```

I've also tried obliterating the default test.ts file that is currently put in place by Karma and changing it to

```
import test from 'ava';
test('BLA', t => {
  t.pass();
});
```

In the hopes that I could at least bootstrap **something** to work with that I could maybe use to add/implement the rest of our test files with later. So far I've had no luck with this either.

Can someone who has taken this path before tell me what needs to be done to get the Ava test runner up and working; and furthermore, what may need to be done to adapt our currently existing karma/jasmine based test framework to Ava?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVA currently only supports test files with a `.js` extension. You should precompile your TypeScript test files and change the `files` pattern to match the tests inside your build directory.

Comment: Is there seriously no other way to do this without a pre-processor that converts the files? A few of the open issues on the AVA project seem to suggest that there are ways to do this where this isn't necessary.

Comment: There's a lot of people saying it should be easy for their use case, which is correct, but that makes other use cases more difficult. Hence no, currently there is no other way to do this. There's a plan, but there's only so many OSS-hours in a week.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this answer while searching for something else, and realized it might be worth chiming in, even though it's been a bit since the question was asked.

There *is* a path to run AVA + TS via `ts-node`. Additionally, there's a `tsconfig-paths` package that aids in correctly mapping to `tsconfig`'s `paths` property, if being used.

Below is what the AVA config would roughly look like. Of course, your paths may be different based on your Angular CLI project structure, but the same basic principles apply:

```
"ava": {
  "compileEnhancements": false,
  "extensions": [
    "ts"
  ],
  "require": [
    "ts-node/register",
    "tsconfig-paths/register"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/index.ts"
  ],
  "failWithoutAssertions": true
}
```

Additionally, you may have a testing-specific `tsconfig`, in which case you'd need to point to it via a `TS_NODE_PROJECT` environment variable that `ts-node` will pick up on. So, for example, you're `test` task might look like this:

```
TS_NODE_PROJECT=tsconfig-spec.json node_modules/.bin/ava --verbose
```

Note that because Node natively consumes only CommonJS (at least at the time of this writing), your `tsconfig` will need to compile to that module format. So, continuing the example above, your `tsconfig-spec.json` might look like this, among other desired options:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

The API between AVA and Jasmine is not the same, but it's actually, in my experience, similar enough that the conversion isn't too painful—mostly mechanical. At the time of this writing, there's an issue open to [create a codemod for the conversion](https://github.com/avajs/ava-codemods/issues/22); however, it looks like it hasn't had much traction yet.